# When using xhprof profiling PHP code, how to prevent it from destroying the Ajax call from the JavaScript client?

Tags: php, profiling, xhprof

When I am using xhprof profiling [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code, it works fine.
I reference the documentation written by Lorenzo Alberton, http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/.

But you know that we always have many Ajax calls in a web application. When I try to include `header.php` and `footer.php` in this article, how can I prevent it from destroying the Ajax call from the JavaScript client?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue. I fixed it by adding the following lines at the top of the Ajax responding script.

```
global $_xhprof;        
@$_xhprof['display'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the "Profiler Output" link from your code ?
xhprof shouldn't be changing anything since It's just a profiler.

You can try a if !is_ajax to hide it on ajax requests.

```
function is_ajax()
{
return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest');
}
```

Comment: yes I just want to remove "Profiler Output", but how can I only remove it when the request is a ajax call?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it will work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to program in the exception URLs in your `config.php` (https://github.com/preinheimer/xhprof/blob/master/xhprof_lib/config.sample.php)

The application will not display the footer link on those URLs (the feature was designed with this use case in mind).